# how would I count duplicates, sum rows of the duplicates, and output that data in MS Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, function

### Beginning:

I'll start with I have no idea how to accomplish what I am asking, which is why I am posting.

I tried using a `COUNTIF` but the logic escapes me for what I am attempting.
I would gladly offer up code if I were capable of writing it.

### Sheet Mock-up:

```
Berry Mixer     Strawberry  2.20        *Berry Mixer    5.80
Berry Mixer     Grape       1.50        *Pumpkin Spice  2.20
Berry Mixer     Blueberry   2.10        *Blitz          5.60
Pumpkin Spice   Pumpkin     0.60
Pumpkin Spice   Cream       0.40
Pumpkin Spice   Well Rum    1.20
Blitz           Skyy        4.00
Blitz           Coke        1.00
Blitz           Cherry      0.60
```

### Problem:

I am trying to write either functions, or VBA, that will:

- 1. Count the duplicates in Column A (*a countif will do that*)
- 2. Write that duplicate to Column D Row 1
- 3. Add the rows, specific to the duplicate, and output in Column E Row 1
- 4. Repeat contentiously for the next series of duplicates, infinitely

I know C# but that doesn't help me, as I do not know calls in Excel and the Designer View hasn't been all that helpful.  I have attempted to look things up, like `CountIF`, `SumIF` and Pivots, except I do not want to enter a value to search for as the table is HUGE! I'd like to discover how to just "make it work" based on the information entered into the sheet.

If you have any suggestions, I would **REALLY** appreciate it as I've been banging my head against the wall. I understand the logic, I just have no idea how to "do"

I would really appreciate any and all suggestions! Thank you kindly.
My bad on the formatting ... blockstyle doesn't seem to want to work?

Comment: It's hard to tell what's in which cell from your attempted table. Can you confirm? Also, it might be worth adding your expected results for that dataset so that it's clear what you're seeking.

Comment: Perfect problem for a Pivot Table

Answer (score 0):

A Pivot table will do most of what you want.

- Put Labels at the first row of your columns
- Select your first three columns
- Insert / Pivot Table
- Drag the First column to Rows and the Third column to Values
- Copy the resultant data and paste it into columns D:E